# Django, sending emails through Mandrill without language_code setting

Tags: python, django, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill API to send emails. The problem is that the emails don't have the proper `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting that I used in `settings.py`

In my settings.py file I have the following lines:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "events.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
)
...
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

In `managment/commands/sendmails.py`, some of the code to send emails is:

```
def generate_html(events):
    template = loader.get_template('mail_request_list.html')
    return template.render(Context({'events': events}))

def send_emails():
    mandril_client = mandrill.Mandrill(key)
    message = {
        'from_email': 'info@myapp.com',
        'from_name': 'myapp',
        'subject': u'Title',
    }

    events = get_events() #Other function
    html_request = generate_html(events)
    message['html'] = html_request
    message['to'] = [{
        'email': 'test_user@myapp.com',
        'type': 'to'
    }]
    mandril_client.messages.send(
         message=message
    )
```

The html file `mail_request_list.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<body>
{% for event in events %}
    Mes: {{ event.begin_at|date:'F'|lower }} 
    <br>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I can send emails, but the dates shows in english and not in spanish how is set in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to appropriately set [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format) in your `settings` file, the `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting is not responsible for formats of any kind.